# Julia cant find module even though it knows it is installed

Tags: module, julia

I am trying to run a simulator called FLOWUnsteady. At one point, Julia complains:

```
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= C:\Users\dsfjk\.julia\packages\PyCall\L0fLP\src\pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>
ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'scipy'")
```

but at the same time:

'''
julia> Pkg.add("SciPy")
Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `C:\Users\dsfjk\.julia\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
No Changes to `C:\Users\dsfjk\.julia\environments\v1.7\Manifest.toml`
'''

How does it not see the package it itself installed?

Comment: You should include the sequence of steps you are following, in order. What command did you run to get the first error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error Julia tries to load `scipy` via the `PyCall` and does not see it.

The easiest way to replicate it would be:

```
using PyCall
pyimport("scipy")
```

Assuming you will see the same error, the problem is that the module `SciPy.jl` does not install Python scipy until it is used for the first time. This can be solved easily by loading the module:

```
julia> using SciPy
[ Info: Installing scipy via the Conda scipy package...
[ Info: Running `conda install -y scipy` in root environment
...
```

Another option is to add Python scipy manually to your Julia installation:

```
using Conda
Conda.add("scipy")
```